# How can I get slowmoVideo installed on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: slowmovideo

I am new at this (Ubuntu) and I cannot get it to work. These were my steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:brousselle/slowmovideo
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And I got this:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/brousselle/slowmovideo/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in https://launchpad.net/~brousselle/+archive/ubuntu/slowmovideo, there is no `slowmovideo` package for Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty). However, you get `slowmovideo` using the PPA at https://launchpad.net/~ichthyo/+archive/ubuntu/video instead by doing the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ichthyo/video
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install slowmovideo
```

Comment: Just a note: sometimes PPAs have many packages, and it's hard to see for which version are there ones. So they could also open the [½ way URL they see in the error](http://ppa.launchpad.net/brousselle/slowmovideo/ubuntu/dists/), and check if there's a name of their Ubuntu version.